# SharePoint Search Box - Restriction Keyword Queries

Tags: 2013, search, search-results, keyword-set, property-restrictions

BACKGROUND - 
I will be conducting a tutorial for SharePoint users on **How to use the Search Box effectively**, to use Keywords Queries in the search box to filter their search results and making files searching much easier for the users i.e.:

```
1) author:"John Smith" author:"Jane Smith"
2) author:Shakesp*
3) filetype:docx
```

One question, is there a Restriction Keyword Queries that can search ONLY in **Specific Document Library** and **Custom List**.

e.g. SearchIn'America'DocumentLibrary: Food

This will find all Food mentions in the 'America' Document Library.

Comment: You can use the "path:" parameter

Comment: @Robert Lindgren ah, that's a good idea! However the path can be really long, are there any ways to shorten it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use query rules to achieve this. Look at using specific "Action Terms" and convert those terms to specific queries.